# Databricks Spark Partition Pruning Doesn't work with large IN statement

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

We have a large table of several hundreds of GB's. We receive incremental data from a specific key. Current setup is that we have a ZORDER on that 1 KEY. We use MERGE INTO

When we use 10 distinct keys the ZORDER functionality works as expected:
[image]

We see only a small size of the data is being read:
[image]

However when we have a distinct number of keys higher than 10 the whole table gets read:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how we can resolve this limitation?

Comment: is it partitioned by that, or only ZOrdered?

Comment: It is partitioned on YYYYMM and ZORDER BY 1 column defined in my IN clause